# Solving SAT problem using Z3 without repeating Boolean expression

Tags: z3, smt, sat

Let's look at the following problem: `f(a, b, c, x, y, z)` is a Boolean function where a, b, c, x, y and z are Boolean values, and the output of f is a boolean value. The definition of f consists of a number of and/or/nor operators. I want to find a set of three Boolean values x0, y0, and z0, such that:

```
f(0, 0, 0, x0, y0, z0) = 0 AND
f(0, 0, 1, x0, y0, z0) = 1 AND
f(0, 1, 0, x0, y0, z0) = 1 AND
f(0, 1, 1, x0, y0, z0) = 0 AND
...
f(1, 1, 1, x0, y0, z0) = 1 # A total of 8 constrains. Each of them is from an entry in the truth table.
```

A naive approach is to define 3 Boolean variables x, y, z, and repeatedly define the function `f` 8 times. However f consists of complex boolean expressions. Defining it 8 times can blow up the model. Moreover, in fact, I have 7 variables: a, b, c, d, e, f, g. The truth table has 128 entries.

Is there a way to define something like a "placeholder" variables a, b, c which are not part of the solution? I can then define f on a, b, c, x, y, z only once, and later somehow "assign" a, b, c to Boolean constants.

I'm a newbie on SMT solvers, the placeholder idea might be totally irrelevant. Other solutions are appreciated as well.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to decipher exactly what you are trying to do. But it seems to me that your concern is about how to code this easily, as opposed to anything else. If so, I'd recommend programming in a language that provides a higher-level API than SMTLib. You can use many of the interfaces z3 supports: C, C++, Java, etc., to simplify the programming task.

For instance, here's how one can use the Python interface to code an instance of your problem:

```py
from z3 import *

def fOriginal(a, b, c, x, y, z):
    return Or([a, b^c, x, y, z])

x0, y0, z0 = Bools("x0 y0 z0")

def f(a, b, c):
    return fOriginal(a == 1, b == 1, c == 1, x0, y0, z0)

s = Solver()

s.add(f(0, 0, 0) == False)
s.add(f(0, 0, 1) == True)
s.add(f(0, 1, 0) == True)
s.add(f(0, 1, 1) == False)
s.add(f(1, 1, 1) == True)

print(s.check())
print(s.model())
```

When run, this prints:

```
sat
[y0 = False, z0 = False, x0 = False]
```

Giving you an assignment to `x0`, `y0`, and `z0` as you're trying to find.

The idea here is to code `f` as a regular function, using z3's interface. I called this function `fOriginal` in the python code. We then define a version of `fOriginal`, which I called `f` in the code, which passes symbolic values for the last three arguments, but expects constants for the first three.

We then simply add the constraints for each of your cases. I added only 5 above following your example; you can add all 8 of course.

I hope this gets you started!

Comment: Thanks. My concern is model complexity, not clean coding. The Boolean expression is defined 5 (or 8) times. That's what worries me.

Comment: I don't think model complexity will be an issue for that size. If you use quantifiers, it'll definitely be more complicated for the solver to address the problem anyhow. I recommend try it out and only deal with complexity if you observe any.

Comment: I'm trying to build a 7 segment display decoder circuit using minimal number of NOR gates. Given a 4-bit to 7-bit Boolean function, it basically searches an equivalent circuit. The code is at https://gist.github.com/wuyongzheng/ab0be78beb3c15d000c32b6c8b773516. With `num_gates = 13`, it gives unsat after 2 minutes. With more gates, it runs for too long.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me what you need the model for and how much flexibility you need, but here is an idea: if it is acceptable to constrain the function on all argument values, via a single else-case, then the following might work:

```
(declare-fun f (Bool Bool Bool Bool) Bool)

(assert (forall ((x Bool) (y Bool) (z Bool) (p Bool)) (!
  (=
    (f x y z p)
    (ite
      (and (not x) y) true (ite         ; 1. case
      (and (not x) (not y) z) true (ite ; 2. case
      (and x (not y) z) true            ; 3. case
      false))))                         ; else-case
  :pattern ((f x y z p)))))
```

At least for this simple case, Z3's model effectively ignored the irrelevant 4th parameter of function `f`:

```
(check-sat) ;; SAT --> good
(get-model)  
; NOTE: 4th parameter x!3 is declared, but not used
; (model 
;   (define-fun p () Bool
;     false)
;   (define-fun f ((x!0 Bool) (x!1 Bool) (x!2 Bool) (x!3 Bool)) Bool
;     (or (not (or x!0 (not x!1)))
;         (not (or x!1 (not x!2) (not x!0)))
;         (not (or x!1 x!0 (not x!2)))))
; )
```

Comment: The crucial bit of information is that it's necessary to use a quantifier (and there are various encodings that all differ slightly). The problem with that is that the solver will behave much less predictable and it will often take a lot more time than for some small number of copies of `f` in the quantifier-free encoding. In some cases, if there are no "obvious" simplifications, the solver will also produce all possible combinations of values that you would list manually (e.g. by MBQI).